# Regular Grammar and Regular Language

Tags: regular-languages

My doubt is based on the relation between regular grammar and regular languges

$S \to Sa\ |\ a$ produces the regular language $a^+$ but this grammar is not type-3 grammar of Chomsky classification. So am I correct in stating that this is not a regular grammar even when it produces regular language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me quote the wikipedia entry for [linear grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar):

> Two special types of linear grammars are the following:
>
> 1. the left-linear or left regular grammars, in which all nonterminals in right hand sides are at the left ends
> 2. the right-linear or right regular grammars, in which all nonterminals in right hand sides are at the right ends.
>
> Collectively, these two special types of linear grammars are known as
>   the regular grammars; both can describe exactly the regular languages.

As you can see, your grammar is a left-linear grammar, and it generates a regular language. Type-3 grammars of the [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) can be defined as right-linear grammars or as left-linear grammars, as you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

Also notice that the grammar $G$ with the following production rules:
$$S\rightarrow aSa | aS |a$$
Generates the regular language $a^+$: 
$$L=\mathscr{L}(a^+)=L(G)$$
But $G$ is a context-free grammar(type 2). This is perfectly fine because a regular grammar always generate a regular language but a regular language can be generated by all types of grammar in the Chomsky's Hierarchy.